# Can't git add . to stage files in new repo

Tags: git

I've initialized a new git repo, and done `git init` then `git add .`, and it still shows all the files in the directory as untracked files when I do `git status`. It just lists the main directory in untracked files and none of the files in the folder.

I've tried doing `git add --all ./` also with no change.  I've also tried deleting my .gitignore file and running `git add .` again, to see if maybe it was blocking too much with no change (other than .gitignore no longer being an untracked file, since it's gone). I've also checked for .git folders in all the parent directories of this one to make sure I'm not within another repository.

Here's output from `git status`:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
    .gitignore
    README.md
    apprentice/
    data-access/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Also, I can get .gitignore and README.md to stage by typing `git add <filename>` where  is either .gitignore or README.md.  That doesn't work on either of the two directories though, and I'm primarily interested in committing the files in the directories.  I would expect `git add .` to pick up both files and the directories and their contents.

Comment: Show your gitignore?

Comment: And what are in the directories? git doesn’t track directories; it only tracks the files within them.

Comment: The directories do have content.  I'm not sure why it's ignoring it.  

The .gitignore in question works in other repositories without problems, but I tried removing it anyway with no change.  It's fairly large.

Comment: The problem seems to be local to this machine.  I moved the same files to another machine via Dropbox, then did `git init`, `git add .`, and `git commit -m "message"` then pushed them all to github without a problem.  I'm using "git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)" on this laptop where it isn't working.

Comment: I tried updating to "git version 2.20.1", but it didn't help.

Comment: Aha, you are on a Mac. I think someone—possible Apple themselves—is/are distributing broken versions of Git for MacOS. I'm not sure precisely what is broken, though my suspicions lead towards the fancy new fsmonitor system.

Comment: I tried in another repo.  Still in ~/git.  It failed to add files there also.  I tried deleting the directory and checking out the repo fresh from github and then adding to it, but it turned out the same.  I also tried changing my shell, in case I had a zsh plugin messing it up, but it's just as broken in bash.

Comment: I was hoping that I got rid of any Mac weirdness by switching from the Apple Git version to version 2.20.1.  I installed it via homebrew, but it's the same version listed here: <https://git-scm.com/download/mac>

Comment: Even weirder.  It seems to work through the GitHub Desktop client.  I added the directory fine and pushed it up.  But I was unable to do the same through command-line git.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rule out any gitignore rule, type:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git check-ignore -v -- apprentice/aFile_which_should_be_added
```

You will see immediately if there is a .gitignore (local or global) rule preventing any file to be added.

Try also to add a file directly:

```
git add apprentice/aFile_which_should_be_added
```

Compare it with:

```
git add -f apprentice/aFile_which_should_be_added
```

Comment: I tried the check-ignore command, and it had no output.

I tried `git add apprentice/java/commit-info/Dockerfile` and it staged the single file, and then listed other files in the apprentice/java/commit-info directory as specifically untracked, rather than just listing the directory as untracked.

When I tried with `-f`, it just seemed to do the same thing as add without `-f`.  Staged the individual file and listed other files in the same directory as untracked.

Comment: Now that you have added one file, can you try and add the apprentice folder, to see if git status output changes?

Comment: Tried adding apprentice/ after adding apprentice/java/commit-info/build.gradle, but `git status` didn't change for apprentice/.  `git status` doesn't change for `git add .` either after adding the single file.  It only changed when I added the single file.